# Is there an animation-play-state property in SVG animation?

Tags: animation, svg

I am animating svg elements using `<animate>`. Is there an equivalent property to the `animation-play-state` property in CSS animation in SVG animation? I've looked at this documentation [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin) and it seems that there isn't one, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Something like this: [SVGAnimationElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement)?

Answer (score 3):

This website [Introduction to  SMIL animation in SVG](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/smil_svg.html) is useful. From it I learned that `beginElement()` and `endElement()` in a JavaScript script, can be used to start and end animations.

The `begin` attribute should be set to `indefinite`. An example is shown below.

JS

```
    function start(id){
    D.getElementById(id).beginElement()
    }
```

SVG

```
    <ellipse fill="lightpink" onclick="start('A')" cx="40" cy="140" rx="22" ry="14">
     <animate id="A" attributeName="cx" dur="3s" begin="indefinite" values="40;400;40"/>
    </ellipse>
```

If an animation tag A contains the attribute `end="indefinite"` then `A.endElement()` will succeed in terminating that animation.

Also, a JavaScript call to `document.documentElement.pauseAnimations()` will stop all SMIL animations within an SVG document, freezing objects at their current position.

`document.documentElement.unpauseAnimations()` resumes SMIL animations from whatever position they were paused at. More about `pauseAnimations()` and `unpauseAnimations()` here at [W3C](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#InterfaceSVGAnimationElement) and [MDN Docs: SVGSVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement).